# I keep on getting the error "Time Limit Exceeded" in a C program.How should i make my code efficient?

Tags: c, loops

> Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers! The input begins with the number `t` of test cases in a single line (`t <= 10`). In each of the next `t` lines there are two numbers `m` and `n` (`1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n - m<=100000`) separated by a space.

I don't know how to solve the problem with advanced concepts so I solved it by using just loops.

The time limit to this problem is 6.00s

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[1],b[1],j,i,test,k,flag;
    scanf("%d",&test);
    for(i=1;i<=test;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<1;k++)
        {
            scanf("%d %d",&a[k],&b[k]);
        }
        for(j=a[0];j<=b[0];++j)
        {
            flag=0;
            for(k=2;k<j;++k)
            {
                if(j%k==0)
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag==0)
            {
                printf("\n%d",j);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: an array of `1` element? why not a single variable?

Comment: Please link the source of the question.

Comment: The array declarations are the bug, indexing the array beyond element 0 corrupts the loop variable values.  Making the loops loop much more than intended.  Use a debugger to find mistakes like this.

Comment: Are you writing Peter's homework? You have loops written to guarantee only one iteration: Peter should double-check your work.

Comment: For starters change `for(k=2;k<j;++k)` to `for(k=2; k<=sqrt(j); ++k)`

Comment: I don't know what qualifies for you as an "advanced concept", but it seems likely that the problem and associated test cases are designed so as to require something at least a little cleverer than your very simple approach.

Comment: For example, check each candidate `j` only for divisibility by primes less than or equal to the square root of `j`.  To that end, pre-compute the list of primes you will need, perhaps via the [Seive of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @John Actually I'm not familiar with many concepts because I'm still in the process of learning.So,i could no think of any other approach rather than using for loops.

Comment: @Yash131997, we're all still in the process of learning.  Some of us are just farther along than others.  The points of my comment were (1) your question leaves us doubtful about what kind of answers would be appropriate for you, and (2) you probably in any case need a more sophisticated approach.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of suggestions that will improve performance.

1. You don't need to check all the way to `b[0]`. You need to check only up to `sqrt(b[0])`.
2. Update the loop so that you check only odd numbers not all numbers.

Replace

```
for(j=a[0];j<=b[0];++j)
{
```

by

```
int stop = sqrt(b[0]);
// Start with an odd number and keep incrementing j by 2 to keep it that way
for(j= (a[0]/2)*2+1; j <= stop; j +=2 )
{
```